# Will a method annotated with @PostConstruct be guaranteed to execute prior to a method with @Scheduled within the same bean?

Tags: java, spring

Say I'm defining a caching bean which will be initialized upon launch of the application and will be refreshed at a fixed interval as seen below:

```
@Component
public class Cache {

     ...

     @PostConstruct
     public void initializeCache() {
     ...
     }

     @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60L * 1000L)
     public void refreshCache() {
     ...
     }

}
```

Will the initializeCache() method under @PostConstruct be guaranteed to execute immediately before the first scheduled refreshCache() call even if I don't set an initial delay?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the method annotated with `@PostConstruct` is guaranteed to execute first.

The `@Scheduled` annotation is activated by [ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L218) which is invoked *after* any bean initialization callbacks (like InitializingBean's afterPropertiesSet or a custom init-method).

Comment: Does this hold across components in general, or does the dependency need to be explicit?