# How can I make init method before called @Scheduled method in spring class?

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

**This is my java class**

```
@Component
public class ReportTasckScheduler {
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        List<ReportTasck> allByStatus = reportTasckRepository.findAllByStatus(1);
        if (allByStatus.isEmpty()) return;
        for (ReportTasck allByStatu : allByStatus) {
            allByStatu.setStatus(0);
            allByStatu.setStartDate(new Date());
            reportTasckRepository.save(allByStatu);
        }
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)  //раскоментировать для шедлинга
    public void startSchedule() throws IOException, NurException {
        //code
    }
}
```

Can I be sure that `init()` wiil called before `startSchedule()` always?
if not, how do I make my check is always called during initialization, before the first start  `startSchedule()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PostConstruct` will be invoked *during* the bean initialization. The `Scheduled` method will be invoked *after* the bean was initialized.
Please note that this bean exists only once in your Spring context, so that `PostConstruct` will be invoked only during startup.

See also this answer: [Will a method annotated with @PostConstruct be guaranteed to execute prior to a method with @Scheduled within the same bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304743/will-a-method-annotated-with-postconstruct-be-guaranteed-to-execute-prior-to-a)

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the annotation to schedule the task, inject a TaskScheduler into your class and then schedule the task programamticaly at the end of your init method

e.g.

```
@Inject
private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

....
```

then

```
taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(this,5000);
```