# How to do some preprocessing before starting Spring Boot Scheduler?

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduler

I want to have some basic preprocessing code that need to be run only once before starting the scheduler everytime. How can we achieve the same in Spring Boot ?

Comment: Is it an option to start that preprocessing when spring boot launches?

Comment: What sort of "basic preprocessing code", specifically?

Comment: Do you want to do pre-processing before each scheduled job starts to run?

Comment: I want to do pre-processing only once at application startup and then scheduler code can get executed as many number of times. But in case the application stops and restarts, I want the preprocessing to run again before running scheduler

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this? There are other options as well. But please elaborate the question.

```
@Component
public class Cache {

     ...

     @PostConstruct
     public void initializeCache() {
     ...
     }

     @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60L * 1000L)
     public void refreshCache() {
     ...
     }

}
```

Credits: [Will a method annotated with @PostConstruct be guaranteed to execute prior to a method with @Scheduled within the same bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304743/will-a-method-annotated-with-postconstruct-be-guaranteed-to-execute-prior-to-a)

Comment: Welcome.. If you have posted some code, others would have easily given this solution earlier..  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run code only once you could wait until Spring is ready and then run the code. To achieve this you could listen for the event like this:

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void doSomethingAfterStartup() {
  System.out.println("run your code here");
}
```

You can put that code in the application class to see the results.

Comment: I don't think that she means that! She wants to do pre-processing before each scheduled job is triggered after application starts.

Comment: Scheduler is getting executed before ApplicationReadyEvent. What I want is to block the scheduler till thi preprocessing gets executed completely. That too only at Application startup not before every scheduler job run.

Comment: Could you please somehow rephrase what you want. I don‘t quite get it.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @AnandVarkeyPhilips I am still looking. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the scheduler code.. in the question? Is it in loop or something? i think I have a solution